# 10 bit i2c Digital to Analogue Converter

Tags: python

my very first post - so please be gentle

Raspberry Pi Zero - Python3, AD5325 10 bit [DAC](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5305_5315_5325.pdf)

I realise I'm probably biting off more than I can chew for such a python beginner - but I do have some basic programing experience and there is nothing like trying to make something real actually work. What I'm trying to do is convert my working 'basic' uC code to Python for use on the Pi

This is the working code in basic

```
W_Data_DAC=W_Data_DAC*3.41                             'value between 0 and 300 - scaled to 10 bits
Clear B_DAC_pnt                                        'clear the pointer
B_DAC_pnt.2=1                                          'set for DAC C
W_Data_DAC=W_Data_DAC<<2                               'shift left 2 places (to fit the DAC requirements)
W_Data_DAC.12=0                                        'set to update all channels
W_Data_DAC.13=1                                        'Normal Operation
BusOut Ad5315,[B_DAC_pnt,B_Hi_DAC,B_Lo_DAC]            'update each DAC
```

So I start of with a word size variable between 0 - 1023 (10 bits) W_Data_DAC

set bit 2 of a pointer byte (B_DAC_pnt) - instruct to write to ch C

shift W_Data_DAC left 2 places

clear W_Data_DAC bit 12 - instruct to update all ch

set W_Data_DAC bit 13 - instruct normal operation

then write 3 bytes to the DAC via the i2c bus

This is the code I have so far in Python

```
import smbus
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM) # GPIO Numbers instead of board numbers
#GPIO.setwarning(False) # no warnings

Coil_1 = 17
Coil_2 = 27
Coil_3 = 22

chan_list = [Coil_1,Coil_2,Coil_3]
GPIO.setup(chan_list, GPIO.OUT)


#GPIO.setup(Coil_1, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode
#GPIO.setup(Coil_2, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode
#GPIO.setup(Coil_3, GPIO.OUT) # GPIO Assign mode


bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
adc_add=0x4d            #ADC address
dac=0x0c                #DAC address


def an_in():    #read the current analogue input
    result=bus.read_i2c_block_data(adc_add, 0x00, 2)
    test1=(result[0]<<8)+result[1]
    v_in=test1*0.001221
    return v_in

def an_out(v_out):              #v_out will be a value 0 to 300 from the calling routine)
    v_out=v_out*3.41            #range now 0-1023 10 bits
                                #convert this a 16 bit word
    W_Out=int(v_out)            # convert to an integer (? 16 bits)
    W_out=W_out<<2              #shift left 2 places
    W_out=W_out | 12288         #Logocal OR to set bit 13
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(dac,W_out)


while True:
    #run through the relays
    GPIO.output(Coil_1, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(Coil_1, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(Coil_2, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(Coil_2, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(Coil_3, GPIO.HIGH)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    GPIO.output(Coil_3, GPIO.LOW)
    time.sleep(0.5)



    #This reads the state of the PCF8574 Port Expander / anlg input
    result=bus.read_byte(0x20)
    print('Dig Input ',format(result,'08b'))
    print('Anlg In = ',format(an_in(),'f'))
    an_out(an_in)    #call the DAC value 0-300


    time.sleep(2)
```

as you can see - I have 3 relays, 1 ADC and a DAC - ok with the first 2 parts, but a bit stumped with the DAC.

The output I'm getting is:

Dig Input  11111111

Anlg In =  3.632475

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "i2c.py", line 67, in 
an_out(an_in)    #call the DAC value 0-300

File "i2c.py", line 34, in an_out
v_out=v_out*3.41            #range now 0-1023 10 bits

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'

I suspect I'm making a number of very basic errors here - but my approach to learning is 'bite off more than you can chew - then chew like mad'

Specifically my questions are - why I can't call the function an_out(an_in)?
and why can't I multiply the variable v_out by 4.31 - I haven't specified the var as an integer anywhere?

Also - I suspect this is not the correct way to write to the DAC in this case anyway?

This question is as much me 'dipping my toe' as it it trying to solve a particular problem - my next challenge is figuring out my toolchain (vim seems very clunky - I'm after an IDE that works headlessly and has a good debugger - I get a lot of bugs :-)

Any help or advice would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Read the error message - it is telling you that the parameter value of `vout` isn’t a number, it’s a function. Looking at your call `an_out(an_in)` the problem is the value that you’re passing as parameter - because you didn’t add `()` you are just using the function name, i.e. you aren’t calling it to get a number - and in Python that’s a valid thing to do, but your function needs a number, so simply change the call to `an_out(an_in())`

Comment: Ok - thanks, really just a syntax error then (lack of understanding of the structure of python)

Comment: Next problem is:

Comment: File "i2c.py", line 37, in an_out
    W_out=W_out<<2              #shift left 2 places
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'W_out' referenced before assignment

Comment: I'll spend the day working through some tutorials I think. That will hopefully saver me :-)

Comment: “Just a syntax error” - no a syntax error would give you an error message and traceback as your py file is loaded by the Python interpreter. You error is a coding mistake - the syntax is valid, but the type of the parameter you are passing in the call is different from what the function expects.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - posted here for future reference

```
import smbus

def an_out(v_out):                                       #0 to 300 (PSI)
    if v_out > 300:
        v_out = 300                                      #max value is 300

    print('Anlg Out = ', v_out)
    v_out = int(v_out * 3.41)                            #scale to 10 bits
    v_out = v_out << 2                                   #shift left 2 places
    mask = 1 << 13                                       #set mask
    v_out = v_out | mask                                 #this should set bit 13
    v_out_hi = v_out & 65280                             #mask out the high byte
    v_out_hi = v_out_hi >> 8                             #shiift down to 8 bits
    v_out_lo = v_out & 255                               #mask out the high byte
    b_pnt=1                                              #DAC Ch C
    command = [(v_out_hi), (v_out_lo)]                   #load the command
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(dac, b_pnt, command)        #i2c (4-20ma out)

    b_pnt=4                                              #DAC Ch A
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(dac, b_pnt, command)        #i2c (0-10v out)
```

I'd be glad if anyone can advise if I have approached this incorrectly or my coding style is not up to scratch (only just starting with python).

Kind regards